# Get host server name through email address in mail core2 framework for iOS

Tags: email, mailcore2

I want to know the default host name through the name of the email address....

I found a method in a class "MCONetService.h"....

```
hostnameWithEmail:
```

the reference link..
http://libmailcore.com/mailcore2/api/Classes/MCONetService.html

...but my problem is that i am unable to find the proper way to use this method because it is an instance method which requires the "MCONetService" class object to call that method,and i am getting null because it seems this object need some value before the use...

my code ...

```
MCONetService *netService=[[MCONetService alloc]init];        
[netService hostnameWithEmail:@"email@gmail.com"];
```

This is not a good way of coding but did't found any other way to try this method...

Any help will be appreciable....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

First, make sure that you include providers.json in the resources of your app.
Here's how to get the IMAP server related to a given email address.

```
NSString * email = @"email@gmail.com";
MCOMailProvider * provider = [[MCOMailProvidersManager sharedManager]
    providerForEmail:email];
NSString * hostname = nil;
if ([[provider imapServices] count] > 0) {
  MCONetService * service = [[provider imapServices] objectAtIndex:0];
  hostname = [service hostnameWithEmail:email];
}
if (hostname == nil) {
  NSLog(@"no IMAP server found");
}
else {
  NSLog(@"IMAP server: %@", hostname);
}
```

Comment: The second line of this code is returning nil, i checked that the "sharedManager" method is not returning nil ,but the "providerForEmail" method is returning nil,I am passing the email to this method...pls let me know the if u are aware with this issue @Dinh Viêt Hoà ...Thanks!!!